# How to call /cart/update.js in debut theme of shopify

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, shopify, shopify-app

All **`shopify`** experts are knowing that default debut theme is not having the version of ajax api.

I am developing my own website where i need to use cart update ajax.

I have tried with below code but it is giving me the errors in console.

```
jQuery.post('/cart/update.js', {updates: {90231456621: 2}});
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: That syntax certainly looks correct, and works on my dev store when I substitute a variant ID for a variant on my shop. Shopify returns a 404 error when the any of the IDs provided do not match a published variant ID in your shop - can you confirm that '90231456621' is a variant ID belonging to a published (visible-on-the-online-store) product?

Comment: Yes when i changed it to variant id it is working thanks for your help.

Comment: No worries!  Glad to help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer:** *(So that other people having similar problems can see that this issue is solved)*

The ID that you were passing was a **product** ID, but the ID that Shopify expects for all of it's add/change/update endpoints is the **variant** ID.  Changing to a legal variant ID should solve the problem.

Cheers!